# Bulk insert to Hbase: ConsumerRecord not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, hbase, rdd

I have a Kafka client that polls a topic for records and stores them as `consumerRecords: ConsumerRecords[String, String]`. I would like to iterate through each record and write the `(offset, value)` as the `(k, v)` to an Hbase table. I am attempting to parallelize these records through Spark so that I can map it to an `RDD` in order to bulk insert to Hbase.

```
val hbaseTable: String = "/app/raphattack/TEST"
val conf: Configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val admin: Admin = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf).getAdmin
val connection: Connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(admin.getConfiguration)
val table: Table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(hbaseTable))

val job = Job.getInstance(conf)
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable])
job.setMapOutputValueClass(classOf[KeyValue])
HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoadMap(job, table)

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
val records: RDD[ConsumerRecord[String, String]] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(consumerRecords.toSeq)

val rdd: RDD[(ImmutableBytesWritable, KeyValue)] = records.map(record => {
  val kv: KeyValue = new KeyValue(Bytes.toBytes(record.offset()), "cf".getBytes(), "c1".getBytes(), s"${record.value}".getBytes())
  (new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes(record.offset())), kv)
})

rdd.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("/tmp/test", classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[KeyValue], classOf[HFileOutputFormat2], job.getConfiguration)
```

I am hitting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Failed to serialize task 0, not attempting to retry it. 
Exception during serialization: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord, value: ConsumerRecord(topic = test, partition = 0, offset = 14691347, timestamp = 0, producer = null, key = 1, value = {"id":1.0,"name":"test"}))
```

Is it possible to make the `ConsumerRecord` object serializable? If not, how else can I iterate through the records without sacrificing write speed to Hbase?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same thing in UnitTest.

Essentially you need to set a serializer at SparkConf

```
.set("spark.serializer", classOf[KryoSerializer].getName)
```